# How to write CSV file form the beginning in TCL, I have a data in rows

Tags: tcl

How to write CSV files in TCL, I have data which I need to put in CSV file I never worked with CSV before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is surprisingly tricky to work with. You can't just blindly join elements with a comma, because the data might have commas in it:

```
set data {42 "value,with,commas" {value "with quotes"}}
puts [join $data ,]
```

```
42,value,with,commas,value "with quotes"
```

That's not the right number of fields. So, let's quote every element.

```
puts [join [lmap elem $data {format {"%s"} $elem}] ,]
```

```
"42","value,with,commas","value "with quotes""
```

But now the inner quotes are broken, so the CSV convention is to double the double quotes.

```
puts [join [lmap elem $data {format {"%s"} [string map {{"} {""}} $elem]}] ,]
```

```
"42","value,with,commas","value ""with quotes"""
```

This is now correct CSV, if overly quoted.
Or, as Colin said, use `csv`

```
package require csv
puts [csv::join $data]
```

```
42,"value,with,commas","value ""with quotes"""
```

Or, if you already have a list of lists representing your data

```
set data2 {{a b c} {d e f} {g h i}}
puts [csv::joinlist $data2]
```

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [CSV module in Tcllib](http://wiki.tcl.tk/38945)